# MATLAB: calculate with first row n times before moving to the next number

Tags: matlab

I am pretty new to Matlab and I could use some help. I have about 50k rows of data. What I would like to do is, that it would take the first number of the data, divide it by 12 and repeat the result 12 times then it would move on to the second number and do the same and so on and on till the end.

Best regards

Comment: you mean like divide by `12^12`?

Comment: If that is the case, then: `A=data/12^12`

Comment: Please add a little more detail to your question.

Comment: Quite hard to understand what you want to do. Try to explane maybe with an example (that you want to replicate on matlab).

Comment: Or, do you mean `repmat(data/12,1,12)`, or even `reshape(repmat(data/12,1,12).',[],1)`?